# How to use Google Colab local runtime and connect to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running Google Colab with a local runtime. I use this command to start Jupyter:

```
jupyter notebook  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

When I previously connected I was able to mount Google Drive with this code in the notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I was able to connect to Google Drive and access files while on local runtime.
However, now I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'
```

I see other people have this problem, and some suggest using PyDrive. But I am certain I was connected to Google Drive without using PyDrive.

I suspect the first command I ran to start Jupyter was different when Google Drive was able to connect.
Is there a specific flag I have to add to that first command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `google.colab` libraries only exist on managed backends.

When running on your local machine, you'll want to instead use Drive's existing sync apps available here: https://www.google.com/drive/download/