# Can't Mount Google Drive in Colab in Local Runtime

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Google Colab in a local runtime and can't seem to load my Google Drive.
I try `from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive')`

but I always get

`````
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-d5df0069828e> in <module>
----> 1 from google.colab import drive
      2 drive.mount('/content/drive')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'````
`````

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008929/how-to-use-google-colab-local-runtime-and-connect-to-google-drive

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")
```

maybe try putting it in this format,
If it does not work try changing your runtime

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't work. What do I need to change? I need to use my own hardware with colab as the hosted runtime limits are not enough and I can't get colab Pro as I'm not in the US

Comment: Did you try changing your runtime?
here is an example notebook = 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q#scrollTo=H4SJ-tGNkOeY'>

Answer (score 0):

The `google.colab` libraries are be available if you are running on your local machine.

Instead, you can use the Google Drive desktop client in order to make your Drive files available on your local machine. See:
https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Comment: Hi, Once I have downloaded the desktop client, how do I load that in Colab? Sorry, extreme beginner here

Comment: After the download and install you'll see another volume mounted on your PC aside disk C: , the you can change directory into that disk from inside a notebook cell running `%cd G:\My Drive` or the other disk where the Drive was mounted